# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in line 125...... in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, fatal-error

I'm trying to filter out the a post type title and I got this

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in line 125

Here is the code I used...

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title', 10, 1);
function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' ){

       $model = get_queried_object('vehicle_model');
       $location = get_queried_object('vehicle_location');
       $title = $model . "used cars for sale in" . $location .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');  <---- this is line 125
    }

    return $title;
    }
```

Comment: Damn, the name suggests that `get_queried_object` must return an object which you just concatenate it with string and does not implement `__toString` I suppose. Try to `var_dump($model, $location)` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_queried_object()` do not allow parameters.

Try this:

```
$post = get_queried_object();
$location = $post->post_title;
```

Maybe your `vehicle_model` and `vehicle_location` are Meta-Fields, Then you must use the [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function

Are you using any Plugin which extends your Post Fields like Advance-Custom-Fields?

EDIT: look comments, you use the ACF plugin. So your code should be:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title', 10, 1);
function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' ){

       $model = get_field('vehicle_model');
       $location = get_field('vehicle_location');
       $title = $model . "used cars for sale in" . $location .'on'. get_bloginfo('name'); 
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Both your suggestions returned just the "used cars for sale on sitename" without the post titles. Yes, I'm using the ACF plugin.

Comment: then you can easily get the values with `get_field('vehicle_model', $postId);` look at the docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Ok I tried that already, it also returned the filtered title without the post titles. I've also tried `$vehicle_location = get_queried_object_id('vehicle_location')` it returns `760used cars for sale in760on sitename`, which seems to be a step closer to the required result . do you have any idea how to change it from an id to a name?

Comment: look always at the documentation on the system. you cant put on `get_quieried_object_id()` an parameter

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I checked. its really confusing now

Comment: it works now. I can already see what I did wrong. Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contents of the $location object you could potentially use `print_r()` to get this into the title.

```
       $title = print_r($model, true) . "used cars for sale in" . print_r($location, true) .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');  <---- this is line 125
```

The `true` tells the function to return the result rather than echo it.

If your object has an internal structure that you need to get data from within then you could do something like this:

```
   $title = $model[0] . "used cars for sale in" . $location[0] .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');  <---- this is line 125
```

A `var_dump($location); var_dump($model);` will output the full contents of the object so you can see their structures. Simply replace the '0' inside the `[0]` with the key (or multiple keys IE `$model[0][0][0]`) of the item you want.

Additionally I see that you already have the post object (`$post`) there. Perhaps you could peek inside that object and see if the model and location is there? `var_dump($post);`

Comment: Ok I tried it out, and it stills returns the same. this is what I got with 'print_r()'    'stdClass( [term_id] => 760 [name] => london [slug] => London [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 760 [taxonomy] => vehicle_location [description] => [parent] => 19[count] => 0[filter] => raw) used cars for sale instdClass Object ([term_id] =>760 [name] => London [slug] => London [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 760 [taxonomy] => vehicle_location [description] => [parent] => 19 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw)on sitename'